# Why isn't Dawn Summers in Chaos Bleeds?

Tags: video-games, buffy-the-vampire-slayer, games

It's been about 2-3 years since I've seen Buffy I finished Buffy seasons 1-4 and Angel season 1. I played Chaos Bleeds ~a decade ago. I'm now watching Buffy season 5 and Angel season 2.

I know what's up with Dawn Summers because I've read about her on Wiki but haven't gotten to that part of season 5 yet.

Why isn't Dawn in Chaos Bleeds? I looked it up online but couldn't find answers. I may be looking in the wrong places or using the wrong keywords.

Update: Now there's

> [image]

and

> [image]

Comment: There are a host of other issues with this game. It's best just to think of it as being set in an alt-universe; http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Buffy_the_Vampire_Slayer:_Chaos_Bleeds#Canonical_Status, one where Spike's chip doesn't stop him from hurting humans, where Faith is out of prison and where vampires can be killed by hitting them really hard.

Comment: Neither of the writers remembers; "*[It's honestly so long ago that I have no idea"](https://twitter.com/ChristophGolden/status/786932561696227328?cn=cmVwbHk%3D&refsrc=email)* - **Christopher Golden** / "*[I have no idea.  I don't remember.  Ask Christopher Golden!  HA!](https://twitter.com/TomSniegoski/status/786938602383110144)"* - **Thomas Sniegoski**

Comment: I've pinned our hopes on Michelle Trachtenberg remembering why she wasn't in it :-) I suspect it'll be something mundane like them wanting to use the same game engine (and characters) from the previous game.

Comment: It's not really much of an answer.

Comment: @Valorum Where's your Michelle Trechtenberg tweet (even if she didn't reply) please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the novelization](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos_Bleeds_(novel)), Dawn is "*staying with her friend Janice*" during the events portrayed, something Buffy is grateful for given the threat level.

> *“Let’s go.” She moved ahead, hefting the bag of Slayer goodies she’d
>   grabbed at her house in her left hand. She hadn’t had time for a
>   shower, but a few extra weapons were never a bad idea and she took
>   care of it. **Dawn wasn’t home, and for a moment she’d been terrified.
>   Then she remembered that her little sister was staying with her friend
>   Janice. It was a risk having Dawn away from home, but on this night
>   that wasn’t exactly a bad thing either. Her sister needed protecting,
>   and better that she be with a regular family for the night than be at
>   home alone when Kakistos was out and roaming the streets.***

The Buffy wikia, however, [disputes the canonicity of the novel](http://buffy.wikia.com/wiki/Chaos_Bleeds_(novel)) as it states that the events take place in the sixth season while the prequel comic states that they take place in the fifth season and "Since the comic was written by the same writers as the game, Christopher Golden and Tom Sniegoski, this setting should take priority."

Comment: As a side note, Dawn is only mentioned four times in the novel according to Google Books, amounting to "Buffy thinks she's doing OK with Dawn", "Spike had seen her take care of her little sister, Dawn", and two mentions in the above bit where she's glad that Dawn isn't at home.

Comment: In the [total absence of any useful response from the writers](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143016/why-isnt-dawn-summers-in-chaos-bleeds/145295#comment363866_143016) this is probably as good an "in-universe" reason as you're going to get. I'd still like to know the out-of-universe reason though.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in the full book quote.

Comment: @BCLC: Not at all. I suspect that Valorum had already passed it up for questionable canonicity, but it may be the best we'll get.